Problem to dowload pdf file using flask api
There is this route to generate a pdf file using 'FPDF' and I need to send it back in response and download with JS directly in browser. I deployed the flask api in vercel and angular UI in github pages. I could already save the pdf in local storage but can't return in request yet.
API related code:
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from fpdf import FPDF


...

@app.route("/test", methods=["POST"])
@cross_origin()
def test():
    pdf = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'A4')
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('helvetica', 'B', 24)
    pdf.cell(0, 10, "Hello World", ln=True, border=False, align='C')

    #pdf.output("file.pdf")
    return send_file(pdf.output(), mimetype="application/pdf", as_attachment=False, download_name="final.pdf")

Angular service code:
const response = await fetch(this.apiUrl, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });

    const data = await response.blob();    


    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');    
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.pdf';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

}

The pdf file downloaded does not open. It seems to be corrupted or something.

"It seems to be corrupted or something" Why don't you open it with a text editor to check the contents?
